# Explain $\log_2(n)$ squared asymptotic run-time for naive nested parallel CREW PRAM mergesort

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, parallel-computing

On from Page 1 of [these lecture notes](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dapa/note3.pdf) it is stated in the final paragraph of the section titled CREW Mergesort:

> Each such step (in a sequence of $\Theta(\log_2\ n)$ steps) takes
>   time $\Theta(\log_2\ s)$ with a sequence length of $s$. Summing these, we
>   obtain an overall run time of $\Theta((\log_2\  n)^2)$ for $n$
>   processors, which is not quite (but almost!) cost-optimal.

Can anyone show explicitly how the sum mentioned is calculated and the squared log result arrived at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to compute this sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) }\mathrm{log}\left( \frac{n}{{2}^{i}}\right)
$$

This can be easily rewritten to:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) }\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) }i
$$

The first term is clearly $(\log(n))^2$. The second term is $(\log(n))^2/2+o((\log(n))^2)$. Summed, the result is $\Theta((\log(n))^2)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, very useful so far. I don't follow how you expanded the second term in the rewritten summation, can you please show this as explicitly as possible?

Comment: That is just because he forgot a factor $\log(2)$. Then it is basic operations on the $\log$.

Comment: @PaulCaheny: Every logarithm in this post (as is usual in the field of computer science) is base 2. Then, $\log(n/2^i) = \log(n) - \log(2^i) = \log(n) - i$.

Comment: @PaulCaheny: $\sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) }i$ is arithmetic series, and a well known result says that $\sum_{i=1}^{n }i = (n+1) \cdot n/2$.

Comment: [TCS Cheat Sheet](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf), at your service.

Comment: @jpalecek Why did you make your first comment "@PaulCaheny: Every logarithm..." ? I understood that and didn't query it.

Comment: @jpalecek Thanks for the further explanation with the well known result $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = (n + 1) (n / 2)$ but doesn't this well known result mean $\sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{log}\left( n\right) }i$ should expand to $(\log(n))^2/2 + ((\log(n))/2)$ rather than $(\log(n))^2/2+o((\log(n))^2)$ as your answer shows?

Comment: @PaulCaheny: The $o(...)$ means little-oh notation, or "asymptotically less than". Because that term is asymptotically less than the leading term (the logarithm squared), it can't play a role in asymptotic analysis (unless the leading term cancels out further, which it doesn't). So I just wrote it as such, not having to think about the exact coefficient etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you were getting at now but in that case shouldn't you have said $= o((\log(n))^2)$ rather than $+ o((\log(n))^2)$ ? Also as an aside - doesn't Big-Oh (Big-Omicron) mean asymptotically less than (as opposed to Big-Omega) whereas little-oh means something stricter (which I don't think is true for the term in question?).

Comment: @PaulCaheny Big-O means 'asymptotically less than or equal to'.  In this case, $\sum_{i=1}^k i = k^2/2+k/2$ (we're using $k=\log n$; the latter term is asymptotically smaller than the first and we don't care about its particular form here, so what jpalecek is writing says that it's $k^2/2+o(k^2)$ - in other words, 'this quadratic term plus some term that's smaller than quadratic'.  You could correctly write the whole thing as $O(k^2)$, because it's asymptotically bounded by a constant multiple of $k^2$ (in fact, $k^2/2+k/2 \lt 1\cdot k^2$ for $k\geq 2$), but that loses useful information.